# Making a multi-threaded timer in C++ Builder using the Win32 API

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, c++builder

I have an application that runs in the main thread. Now I need to start a new thread with a Timer event which has to call a method periodically, every 5 minutes. In that, I need to print the status of the main thread. Even if the main thread dies. I need this second thread to be alive print that the main thread died or had an exception.

I tried out examples, but I don't know how to call the Timer interval, ie I don't know how to implement the periodical call.

Below is the sample code snippet I tried:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

void Thread_Start(void*);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   _beginthread(Thread_Start, 10000, NULL);
   printf("/n RS");
   //   getchar();
   //   return 0;
}

int i = 0;
void Thread_Start(void*)
{
  while (i <50)
  {
    printf("/n Thread Started");
    i++;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could simply `sleep()` in the worker thread, but I would suggest using a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) instead. Or, get rid of the manual worker thread altogether and use [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject) or [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-createtimerqueuetimer) instead to have the OS call a function at timed intervals.

Comment: FYI, if the "main" thread dies, your program will exit, so there is little point in having a second thread monitor the main thread for death/crash.  If you really need that, this would be better handled using a second process instead that monitors the first process for exit.  Not done using threads in a single process.

Comment: It would make more sense when using threads to have the main thread start a separate application thread and a separate monitor thread. In that manner the two threads do not depend upon each other.

Comment: Also printing form outside main thread is dangerous ... as printing involves winapi (behind the scenes of VCL) use ... that usually leads to corruption of winapi calls  when visual winapi calls are done from threads which leads to random crashes in unrelated winapi calls ... so your app could get pretty unstable... safer is schedule prints from your threads into some shared variable/list and then print/render from main thread if needed

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you please elaborate on this . I am new to this development. Kindly share a sample where i can start or kindly give me any tutorials link

Comment: @Spektre That's completely wrong (the parts of it that make any sense).  Windows I/O APIs are perfectly fine to use from multiple threads, and buffering them yourself is much much more likely to introduce race conditions.

Comment: @BenVoigt My experience is that access to any visual stuff on win32 through winapi like any GDI rendering (for example `Canvas->TextOutA` or whatever ) outside main thread (WindProc) causes instabilities. Had problems with it in past on several projects. Most of the time was all OK but time to time random crashes where thrown like once in a week (on 24/7 running)  in unrelated code (like opening file, or dialog window or whatever). After changing architecture to change/render/access visual components only form main thread the crashes stopped...

Comment: @Spektre: The instability was in your code.  No limitations in WinAPI.  Note that the traditional WinAPI (including I/O in kernel32, drawing in gdi32, window management in user32) has only global functions, no such thing as `Canvas->TextOutA`.  So it is likely you were having problems with a wrapper and not WinAPI itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt might be as wrapper was used (VCL) ... however it also might be another reason as this behavior was first detected on 64bit OSes so it also might be related to runing 32 bit code in WOW64 but that is less likely. Btw I wasnt first nor the only one to encounter this problem and the solution wasn't mine either I just tried it and worked on all infected apps... but cant remember where it was suggested anymore it was years ago (before I joined SO).